# How to prove this general inequality $\displaystyle a\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^m+b\left(\frac{\tan{x}}{x}\right)^n>a+b$

Tags: inequality

If $$m,n<0,\;a,b>0,\;a\left[\left(\dfrac{2}{\pi}\right)^m-1\right]\ge b,\;am\le 2bn$$
show that
$$a\left(\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^m+b\left(\dfrac{\tan{x}}{x}\right)^n>a+b,\qquad\forall x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

I know this is Wilker inequality
$$\left(\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^2+\dfrac{\tan{x}}{x}>2$$
and these papers are  GENERALIZED WILKER inequality: [1](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-02-35.pdf) and  [2](http://rgmia.org/papers/v11n2/refine-jordan-kober.pdf).
But my problem is more general. Thank you for your help.

Comment: $m$, $n$ are negative ?

Comment: Hello see [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142874/generalized-wilker-inequality)